# Why variance in R is different?

Tags: r, variance

Calculate variance:

```
v=c(1,2,3)  
print(var(v)) 
#Result:1

#Calculate manually:2/3
```

Comment: Sample vs population variance

Comment: R uses Sample variance

Answer (score 3):

There are typically two ways to estimate variance. One is `1/n * sum( (x-mean(x))^2 )` and another is `1/(n-1) * sum( (x - mean(x))^2 )`. The second is an [unbiased estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator#Sample_variance) for the variance, which R uses.

The comments about sample variance versus population variance seem a bit misleading to me. The population variance is usually thought of as the fixed, unknown variance of a population. We want to estimate that variance, and we do so with a sample of the data, hence a sample variance (which can be estimated in more than one way, as mentioned above).

Comment: Your answer is correct but you should keep in mind that finite populations exist and for some of them you can measure every member of the population.

Answer (score 0):

`var` in R computes sample variance. The other way of doing it is for population variance. http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/numerical-measures/variance